# Windows 10 upgrade compatibility check re-launch

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-10-upgrade

I've got this message on Asus a53s (W7): "Windows 10 can't be installed on this PC", last run 4.7.2015. Report: There are no supported networking devices.

The network devices run properly, I installed the last version of Atheros Wifi driver AR9002wb, but do not know how to relaunch this check. PCs much older than this are all OK and will get win10.

How can I relaunch the Win10 compatibility check?
( I spent more than two hours trying to find any solution but had no any success.)

Comment: [have you looked at this ?](http://www.zdnet.com/article/will-your-pc-run-windows-10-use-this-well-hidden-compatibility-checker-to-find-out/)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Yes, it does not help to solve the issue. I dont have a list of the incompatible devices - the message I get you can see in the question itself. I spent two hours trying to find any solution but had no any success.

Comment: Windows Compatibility center reports against your Windows 10 compatibility check. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=Qualcomm%20Atheros%20AR9002WB-1NG%20Wireless%20Network%20Adapter&Type=Hardware&vendor=Qualcomm%20Atheros

Comment: llan "How can I relaunch the Win10 compatibility check?" your question was pretty clear in your own words.

Comment: If the only issue is a NIC, get a new one, they're about 10 bucks

Comment: @tetsujin  I dont understand your comment

Comment: "Report: There are no supported networking devices." …change the network device [NIC, network interface card]

Comment: @tetsujin the PC in question is a notebook. In addition the wifi card is fully compatible with W10

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has solved.

In general, I reinstalled the WiFi drivers and the GetWindows10 update -

Locate KB3035583 update along "Installed Updates" and Uninstall it.

Now, I performed restart, but I am not sure if it was necessary.

Next, I launched Windows Update and it found the KB3035583 automatically.

Installed it, Restarted, Clicked on the GetW10 icon and voila - "Reserve your W10 free upgrade" bla-bla-bla...

Comment: @Reverse_side_ answer is much better.

Comment: @chriscatfr does it work?

Comment: my apologies, I waited more than 15 minutes but it didn't work. I was quoted on so many websites that it sounded legit...

Answer (score 0):

To relaunch the Hardware compatibility test just use this commande line in cmd with run as administrator permission :

```
schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"
```

You need to wait 15 minutes to get a new report.

And to force Win 10 updating (without booking) :

```
wuauclt.exe /updatenow
```